# Connecting javascript functions to XUL file

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have a `javascript` file connected to my `XUL` file as follows:

```
<script type="application/javascript"
  src="chrome://myexample/content/myexample.js"/>
```

The overlay from the `XUL` file is displayed in Firefox, but my functions aren't working.

e.g.

```
<statusbar id="status-bar"> 
<statusbarpanel id="f1"  
    label="f1"
    onclick = "MyExample.f1()"
  />
</statusbar>
```

`myexample.js` file looks like:

```
var MyExample = {
  f1: function() {
  },
  f2: function() {
  }
}
```

This is my `chrome.manifest`:

```
content   myexample  content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul  chrome://myexample/content/myexample.xul
```

Where could be the fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted, apart from the missing `=` in

```
var MyExample = {
```

...not sure if that's a typo in the original code or just in the snippet here.

Did you set the [javascript.options.showInConsole](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences) and check the Error Console? Are there any messages there when you open the window you try to modify?

You could also be hitting the fact that the chrome code is cached. The effect is that the code you have in your file is not the same code that's running in Firefox. The way to deal with it is to set the disable_xul_cache pref mentioned on the same page as the showInConsole  pref I linked to above (and/or run with `-purgecaches` param). If you have any doubts, make an observable change (i.e. one that *has* to change the observed behaviour, e.g. pops an alert) to the file you think is cached.

[edit] also you could try opening chrome://myexample/content/myexample.js in a tab to see if the chrome.manifest magic is working correctly and you got the URL right, but I guess in your case it's fine.

Comment: It was a type in just snippet in the question :-(

Comment: Is it possible that `firefox 8.0` doesn't allow unpacked extensions? When I try to open `chrome://myexample/content/myexample.js` it shows a message:
`Firefox can't find the file at jar:file:///home/xralf/.mozilla/firefox/pkebutrj.dev/extensions/myexample@xralf.com.xpi!/content/myexample.js.` I will append chrome.manifest to the question.

Comment: minor note: `disable_xul_cache` is not in about:config

Comment: The `error console` reports that `chrome://myexample/content/myexample.xul` was not found. Yesterday I installed `Firefox 8.0` and the extension does not display my XUL either. I guess that the error is in `chrome.manifest`, `install.rdf` and extension name, but I don't know what could be wrong. I installed it with `install from file` option.

Comment: (Re minor note: disable_xul_cache is not the full name and you have to add it to about:config manually.)  You other question indicates a packaging mistake, but doesn't contain enough info. What's "install from file", did you mean you installed the xpi file from the addon manager? what's the xpi contents (`unzip -l /home/xralf/.mozilla/firefox/pkebutrj.dev/extensions/myexample@xralf.‌​com.xpi`)? Firefox tells you there's no ./content/myexample.js in the zip.

Comment: It's installed via `Tools -> Add-ons -> Install Add-on from file ... -> choose myexample@xralf.com.xpi`

Comment: This was my stupid mistake. I forgot the `-r` option when zipping the extension. I'm able to open `chrome://myexample/content/myexample.js` and see my javascript code. XUL file is OK. It shows the designed elements. Only javascript functions and events aren't executed.

Comment: My other stupid mistake was that I forgot to copy the sqlite database to the dev profile. Because no javascript functions were executed I automatically assumed that they won't event start executing. Next time I will rather debug. Thank you for patience, help and precious advises.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `MyExample.` part.